# How to pass value from a python list to a chart?

Tags: python, django

I have to pass two separate value, data and label, from a python list to chartjs.

Here my stuff:

```
data = [[title], [identifier], [subject], [type], [preview], [isReferencedBy], [licence], [licenseMetadata]]
label =["title", "identifier", "subject", "type", "preview", "isReferencedBy", "licence", "licenseMetadata"]

    merge_dataLabel = dict(zip(label,data))

    print(merge_dataLabel)
```

Values in data are the results from a sum, values in label are the corresponding label of each result. To associate each label to the corresponding result I'm using zip with this result:

```
{'title': [309], 'identifier': [309], 'subject': [1], 'type': [309], 'preview': [0], 'isReferencedBy': [0], 'licence': [0], 'licenseMetadata': [0]}
```

Before wasting time to integrate chartjs I tried then to render the result via a template:

```
return render ( request , 'completeness.html' , {'merge_dataLabel': merge_dataLabel})
```

Template:

```
   <ul>
 {% for item in merge_dataLabel %}
 <li>{{ item }}</li>
 {% endfor %}
 </ul>
```

However only the label are rendered without the relative values. So I think that there's something wrong in what I did.

Suggestions?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary variable only shows the key until you explicitly ask for value as shown.

`<ul>
 {% for item,value in merge_dataLabel.items %}
 <li>{{ item }}:{{ value }}</li>
 {% endfor %}
 </ul>`